# how to call function each 10 sec in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

in my html page i have div tag i'm print server side data hear.

```
<div id="chatbox">
   <label>${modelAttribute.chatMessage}<br></label>
</div>
```

First time it is working fine but i'm thinking each and every 10 sec this div will be called function.

so how to call each and every time particular method?

Hear i'm not click any thing

Please suggest me...

Comment: you need to look at [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to call a function every 3 minutes using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491737/trying-to-call-a-function-every-3-minutes-using-javascript)

Comment: Hey Guys.. Why this Question was Closed???? Answering People was Mad!!!! giving to Answer... This Question have Five answers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh your div with all the data using [setInterval()](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/)

```
<div id="chatbox">
//content
</div>
```

And the jquery to refresh the div:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#chatbox").load("getchatbox.php #chatbox");
        }, 10000);
    });

</script>
```

You can also use it with ajax. a nice tutorial here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/04/ajax-update-content-every-x-seconds.html
**Simple example using AJAX**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
function updateData()
{
var html = $.ajax({
url: "/getchatboxdata",
success: function(data) {
$('#chatbox').html(data);
}
});
}

updateData();

var auto_refresh = setInterval(function(){
updateData()
}, 10000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: +1 from me. A fair warning though: `setInterval`will cause stacking if the download takes more than 10 seconds (not likely here, but still a risk - bad/unstable connection). In that regard `setTimeout` is probably a better choice if 10 seconds accuracy is not strictly required (or you can end up with 2+ asynchronous ajax request at once in worse case). Assuming ajax here...

Comment: Thankyou.. is their is any plausibility to write direct function like onload in div tag..

Comment: Yep. you could also use AJAX.

Comment: can you edit your code once with Ajax call?

Comment: Yes there is. This function is called .append() You can call a function when the div is fully loaded. the the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4160706/1379394)

Comment: Updated my answer with a very simple ajax call.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval();` method

you can find more here : 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: Why you downvoted?. I think without setInterval(); you can't do call function on some interval

Answer (score 2):

Use `Ajax method` with `setInterval();`. using this you can easily call function in some interval

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval(function(){ //you can set an AJAX call inside },10000)`  will do the trick for you.

Comment: please explain downvote.

Comment: `setInterval()` by itself can't be used to call server-side functions.

Comment: You can use it with AJAX , as he tagged.

Answer (score 0):

You can uset [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function on window onLoad and pass function which you want to call and time interval

```
window.onload = function() // Start your timer when the window has loaded
{
   setInterval("<function_name>;", <time_interval>); // Using milliseconds, define your 10 second interval
}
```

this will call your function periodically without clicking any where.